# Add two textbox float value and need to display in third text box

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm basically trying to write a basic converter in visual studio 2008, and I have 3 text boxes, two which gets input from the user, and one which gives output with the result.

For Example:

Text box 1:1.0000,
Text box 2:1.12,
Text box1 value + Text box2 value

I should display in Text box 3:1.00001.12

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work? Hint: you'll have to convert each to a floating-point type before you can add them, and back to a string to put in the textbox.

Comment: I convert as a string and i added two(Text box1+Text box2) values.I got result(11.12) like this.

Comment: We need the code for what you tried to see what's wrong with it. A really nice thing to do would be to forget the textboxes and produce an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the same problem, but is a lot smaller and stands alone.

Comment: wstring text3,text2,text1; text3 = text1+text2; For text3 need to set value for an MFC text box control, i got output 11.12 like this, but i want output like this 1.00001.12

Comment: Oh, so you want to concatenate them? It looks like the first is only being given as `1`.

Comment: Ya i got text box1 value is 1. but i need to get 1.0000.

Comment: Well, you could use a `std::stringstream` and `set::setprecision` to force more decimal places, but to do that, you'll have to add the number in after it's been converted to a numeric type, as precision means nothing for a string.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but it seems you require a concat. textbox must be having string not float so whatever you type in it is string you just require to use string concat after that.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
                 textBox3->Text = Convert::ToString(float::Parse(textBox1->Text) + float::Parse(textBox1->Text));
             }
```

Enjoy it.

Answer (score 0):

```
float flowcal1 = 1.0001
float flowcal2 = 1.12

flow.Format(_T("%.4f%.2f"),flowcal1,flowcal2);

flow = 1.00011.12
```